# authorizing a script by running any function does not work

Tags: authorization, google-apps-script

The authorization of a script by starting the Script Editor and running any function doesn't
 work. The skript is published as a web app

Comment: Can you elaborate please ? what error do you get ? what happens ? I don't see any issue on this process right now...

Comment: does this happen every time? I have seen this kind of thing. I have a script with an empty getRights() function and sometimes when I run it the authorization fails to happen. I only know this because when I view the app, I get a authorization error, but running getRights() after I get the authorization error always resolves things. - as serge asks, have you got more details?

Answer (score 0):

There is an [open issue with scripting services to be published as web apps #1703](http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=1703)